# Flickering animation issue in css

Tags: css

I made an animation to look like fire flies but it keeps flickering when starting a new loop

I used `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` but they don't work

https://codepen.io/Triciah101/pen/YmKLzb
this is an example of the code on code pen.

I want the animation to be smooth without the weird flickering it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you start at `translate` position of 0% and finished in another distance at 100%.
Try to match 0% and 100%, so there will be a "combination" in the animation.

Also, you are going from 0% to 2% and changing a lot of distance. This is too fast, and it's causing the unwanted effect.